# Ограниченный список строк в txt

Tags: php, файлы

Как сделать добавление текста в txt файл c определенными условиями?

1. Запись должна быть всегда в начало строки, а не в конец, сдвигая при этом все предыдущие строки вниз.
2. Максимальное кол-во строк для записи должно быть не больше 10.
3. Если в файле уже есть 10 строк, то необходимо удалить самую нижнюю и сделать запись.

Comment: парсиш текст в массив, стрираешь файл, добовляешь в массив в верхнюю строку данные записываешь масив в текст

Comment: Добавление в начало требует безусловно перезаписать весь файл. Байт на диске не подвинешь...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file1 = file("tawr.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES |FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

array_unshift($file1, "ООООООООО");

$result=array_chunk($file1, 10, TRUE);

file_put_contents('tawr.txt', implode("\r\n", $result[0]));
?>
```